# Mouseclick / mousedown / mouseup event not working

Tags: mouseclick-event, mousedown, mouseup

I'm trying to shoot by doing this, but when I click and release it keeps shooting.

```
document.onclick = function(event) {
    socket.emit('movementKey', {
        inputId: 'attack',
        state: true
    });
}
document.onmousedown = function(event) {
    socket.emit('movementKey', {
        inputId: 'attack',
        state: false
    });
}
```

Comment: In which language are you working on?

Comment: This code seems to trigger actions in other code, are you able to include the complete set of code?

Comment: socket.on('movementKey',function(data){
      if(data.inputId === 'left')
          player.pLeft = data.state; //moving left
      else if(data.inputId === 'right')
          player.pRight = data.state; //moving right
      else if(data.inputId === 'up')
          player.pUp = data.state; 
      else if(data.inputId === 'down')
          player.pDown = data.state;
      else if(data.inputId === 'attack')
          player.pAttack = data.state; //if click = true
      else if(data.inputId === 'mouseAngle')
          player.mouseAngle = data.state; 
    });

Comment: Tried to edit it but its not letting me, sorry first time using StackOverflow (its JavaScript /Node.js)